# How to Play a audio file(any format) in Android NDK?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I've tried the below links:
http://audioprograming.wordpress.com/2012/03/03/android-audio-streaming-with-opensl-es-and-the-ndk/

The above example demonstrates echo effect of the recorded voice.Please help me to play a file from the device SD card

Comment: Welcome to SO. The link seems pretty easy to follow; what exactly are you stuck at?

Comment: Thanks Seva Alekseyev for your reply.                                 I am not able to read a audio file from SDcard

Comment: I'm developing an android application in which i want to give sound effects like echo ,Bombarding etc...I've tried in Java ,but failed to find.The best solution i've found is to develop via NDK. Can you please help me with any sample to read an audio file from device SD card in NDK and apply some effects .

Comment: Try the below link: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-ndk/H4P0SAkzMsM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call java method JNI.

You can see how to call the java method in c/c++. Check out the below source.

[Link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/media/jni/android_media_MediaScanner.cpp)